# Extract strings from JSON as array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, phrase

I have the following JSON from Google API and i want to extract `cse_image -> src` and use it in PHP array as `arr[0]` for first , `arr[1]` for second and so on.

```
{
 "kind": "customsearch#search",
 "url": {
  "type": "application/json",
  "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
 },
 "queries": {
  "nextPage": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - Gravity Falls",
    "totalResults": "13600",
    "searchTerms": "Gravity Falls",
    "count": 2,
    "startIndex": 4,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "005215763543692940433:2hdsc4__avm",
    "filter": "0",
    "disableCnTwTranslation": "disable"
   }
  ],
  "request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - Gravity Falls",
    "totalResults": "13600",
    "searchTerms": "Gravity Falls",
    "count": 2,
    "startIndex": 2,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "005215763543692940433:2hdsc4__avm",
    "filter": "0",
    "disableCnTwTranslation": "disable"
   }
  ],
  "previousPage": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - Gravity Falls",
    "totalResults": "13600",
    "searchTerms": "Gravity Falls",
    "count": 2,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "005215763543692940433:2hdsc4__avm",
    "filter": "0",
    "disableCnTwTranslation": "disable"
   }
  ]
 },
 "context": {
  "title": "Gravity Falls"
 },
 "searchInformation": {
  "searchTime": 0.269451,
  "formattedSearchTime": "0.27",
  "totalResults": "13600",
  "formattedTotalResults": "13,600"
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Gravity Falls Apparel - Gravity Falls Wiki",
   "htmlTitle": "\u003cb\u003eGravity Falls\u003c/b\u003e Apparel - \u003cb\u003eGravity Falls\u003c/b\u003e Wiki",
   "link": "http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Falls_Apparel",
   "displayLink": "gravityfalls.wikia.com",
   "snippet": "Gravity Falls apparel are officially sold clothes. On December 11, 2012 \nWeLoveFine.com released...",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eGravity Falls\u003c/b\u003e apparel are officially sold clothes. On December 11, 2012 \u003cbr\u003e\nWeLoveFine.com released...",
   "cacheId": "6Uh7-hm1BKoJ",
   "formattedUrl": "gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Falls_Apparel",
   "htmlFormattedUrl": "\u003cb\u003egravityfalls\u003c/b\u003e.wikia.com/wiki/\u003cb\u003eGravity\u003c/b\u003e_\u003cb\u003eFalls\u003c/b\u003e_Apparel",
   "pagemap": {
    "cse_image": [
     {
      "src": "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130410025818/gravityfalls/images/thumb/5/54/Welovefine_rainbow_gnome.jpg/500px-Welovefine_rainbow_gnome.jpg" //This as arr[0]
     }
    ],
    "cse_thumbnail": [
     {
      "width": "225",
      "height": "225",
      "src": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6kUI6yrCQkhX45BaaylTdDWb9tKvUf2OxwXJJv5NONxG1f0o09YerhB9j"
     }
    ],
    "metatags": [
     {
      "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes",
      "fb:app_id": "112328095453510",
      "og:type": "article",
      "og:site_name": "Gravity Falls Wiki",
      "og:title": "Gravity Falls Apparel",
      "og:description": "Gravity Falls apparel are officially sold clothes. On December 11, 2012 WeLoveFine.com released the first official Gravity Falls merchandise. The same day they launched a Gravity Falls T-shirt design contest which was judged by Alex Hirsch and Michael Rianda. The Grand prize winner received up to $2,000, with several runners up receiving various prizes on top of their own designs becoming part of the online store.",
      "og:url": "http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Falls_Apparel",
      "og:image": "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130410025818/gravityfalls/images/thumb/5/54/Welovefine_rainbow_gnome.jpg/500px-Welovefine_rainbow_gnome.jpg",
      "apple-itunes-app": "app-id=623705389"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Gravity Falls, Oregon - Gravity Falls Wiki",
   "htmlTitle": "\u003cb\u003eGravity Falls\u003c/b\u003e, Oregon - \u003cb\u003eGravity Falls\u003c/b\u003e Wiki",
   "link": "http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Falls,_Oregon",
   "displayLink": "gravityfalls.wikia.com",
   "snippet": "Gravity Falls, Oregon is a mysterious, sleepy, small town in Central Oregon, \nwhere there are many supernatural occurrences. It was founded by Quentin ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eGravity Falls\u003c/b\u003e, Oregon is a mysterious, sleepy, small town in Central Oregon, \u003cbr\u003e\nwhere there are many supernatural occurrences. It was founded by Quentin&nbsp;...",
   "cacheId": "le0YqUje3GYJ",
   "formattedUrl": "gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Falls,_Oregon",
   "htmlFormattedUrl": "\u003cb\u003egravityfalls\u003c/b\u003e.wikia.com/wiki/\u003cb\u003eGravity\u003c/b\u003e_\u003cb\u003eFalls\u003c/b\u003e,_Oregon",
   "pagemap": {
    "cse_image": [
     {
      "src": "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120526133929/gravityfalls/images/thumb/f/fd/S1e1_gravity_falls_oregon_map.jpg/500px-S1e1_gravity_falls_oregon_map.jpg"  // This as arr[1]
     }
    ],
    "videoobject": [
     {
      "thumbnail": "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140905002344/video151/images/thumb/e/ec/Gravity_Falls_-_Referencias_Interesantes/300px-Gravity_Falls_-_Referencias_Interesantes.jpg",
      "duration": "01:47"
     }
    ],
    "cse_thumbnail": [
     {
      "width": "299",
      "height": "168",
      "src": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEsgxZQQYbR400fXDcbDafk6y5Jr9wLjy7ZAV7F3sfBccdhkGnwfiNlPA"
     }
    ],
    "metatags": [
     {
      "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes",
      "fb:app_id": "112328095453510",
      "og:type": "article",
      "og:site_name": "Gravity Falls Wiki",
      "og:title": "Gravity Falls, Oregon",
      "og:description": "Gravity Falls, Oregon is a mysterious, sleepy, small town in Central Oregon, where there are many supernatural occurrences. It was founded by Quentin Trembley, It's where Stan Pines lives and runs the Mystery Shack, a tourist trap which overcharges unlucky visitors for a glimpse at the world's most bizarre museum. Twin siblings Dipper and Mabel Pines are sent to stay with Stan for the summer, which leads them to discover the different yet curious wonders of Gravity Falls. Gravity Falls...",
      "og:url": "http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Falls,_Oregon",
      "og:image": "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120526133929/gravityfalls/images/thumb/f/fd/S1e1_gravity_falls_oregon_map.jpg/500px-S1e1_gravity_falls_oregon_map.jpg",
      "apple-itunes-app": "app-id=623705389"
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Language: PHP

I want to extract JSON using PHP then access it using

`arr[0]`:`http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130410025818/gravityfalls/images/thumb/5/54/Welovefine_rainbow_gnome.jpg/500px-Welovefine_rainbow_gnome.jpg`

`arr[1]`:`http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120526133929/gravityfalls/images/thumb/f/fd/S1e1_gravity_falls_oregon_map.jpg/500px-S1e1_gravity_falls_oregon_map.jpg`

How can i do this with `json_decode` or any other similar method

Comment: But... did you try to use `json_decode`? What were the results?

Comment: Can try using `$data = json_decode($json, true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode($string, true);
echo $data['items'][0]['pagemap']['cse_image'][0]['src'];
echo $data['items'][1]['pagemap']['cse_image'][0]['src'];
```

Comment: Thanks, If you could provide a way to access them using `arr[0]` ,`arr[1]` It would be better :)

Comment: `$arr = array(); foreach($data['items'] as $item) $arr[] = $item['pagemap']['cse_image'][0]['src'];`